# .htaccess rewrite rule not working in production

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Using Apache 2.
I need to rewrite all requested urls from `http://website.dev/file-name.php` in `http://website.dev/file-name`.

Below is the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

SetEnv "ENVIRONMENT" "production"
SetEnv "BASE_URL" "http://website.dev"

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$  $1

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

The solution perfectly works on staging server, but on production (with mod_rewrite already enabled) the request `http://website.dev/file-name` seems to not work and resulting in displaying the `404.php` file.

What I'm missing? Is there any logic or server configuration problem?

Comment: Isn't `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$  $1` doing reverse of what you want?

Comment: did you change your SetEnv "ENVIRONMENT" "development" to production on production server ?

Comment: @n01ze yes i've changed

Comment: @P.Alex working now ?

Comment: @n01ze no, the problem is RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$  $1

Comment: @P.Alex wait let me See

Comment: ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 is redirecting a "/non_existing_file.php" to "/non_existing_file" that"s why you are getting a 404 not found error

Comment: @Starkeen I need to type in browser "sitename.com/file-name" and see "sitename.com/file-name.php"

Comment: @anubhava yes you are right, that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```